# Foreach loop to track two tables at once. sql jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql-server

I have two tables in sql server.
I want to create a loop so my program can $.get() two tables at once.
Currently I can GET one table: Student. I also want to GET Courses also.

How can I do this?

Here is what I have:

```
function Getstudents () {
$.get("/api/students",function (data) {

    $.each(data, function (i, student) {
        $("#studentListTable, .studentlist", function () {
            $(".studentlist").append("<tr><td>" + student.firstName + "</td><td>" + student.lastName + "</td><td>" + student.ssn
                + "</td><td>" + "</td><td>" + courses.length + "<li>" + courses.name + "<\/li>"
                + "</td><td>" +
                "</td><td>" +
                "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-xs toggleButtonActive' >Aktiv</button>" 
                + "</td><td>" + "<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs'data-id=" + "'"
                + "'" + ">Redigera</button>" + "</td></tr>");

        });

        $(document).on("click", ".toggleButtonActive", function (i, student) { 
            if ($(this).hasClass("btn-success")) {
                $(this).removeClass("btn-success");
                $(this).addClass("btn-danger").html("Inaktiv");
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("btn-danger").html("Inaktiv");
                $(this).addClass("btn-success").html("aktiv");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the response syntax you are thinking of making the endpoint return to accomidate returning multiple students and their courses?  Getting the endpoint to return the response in that syntax is your step 1.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL? This is tagged with both, but it also doesn't seem to have any database calls as this looks entirely client-side.

Comment: Microsoft sql server.  Using serializ to make my connection.

 $.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name]) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

Comment: I got some help. Now it works

 function listOfCourses(data) {
            var html = "<ul>";
            $.each(data, function (i, course) {
                html += "<li>" + course.name + "</li>";
            });
            return html + "</ul>";
        }